# Scheduling Timers

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I am using timers to help simulate gravity, and when scheduling the timers based off key presses, key released gives an error saying that the timer is already scheduled or canceled, and im wondering how i can solve it. I want a timer to be scheduled once when the user releases the spacebar, and have it run continuously until it either reaches the bottom or spacebar is pressed. Help is appreciated

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Calendar;



public class Game implements KeyListener {
    JFrame frame;
    JLabel player;

    public boolean grounded = false;
    public int velocity = 0;
    public int finalY = 0;
    public boolean spaceHeld;
    
    public Timer flightTime;
    public TimerTask flight;
    public Timer gravityTime;
    public TimerTask gravity;


    Action spaceAction;

    Game() {
         
        frame = new JFrame("Nicholas Seow-Xi Crouse");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.addKeyListener(this);

        player = new JLabel();
        player.setBackground(Color.red);
        player.setBounds(10, 800, 50, 50);
        player.setOpaque(true);

        frame.add(player);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        flightTime = new Timer();
        flight = new TimerTask() {
         
            public void run() {
                  if(velocity > -5) {
                  velocity -= 1;
                  }
                  else{
                  velocity = -5;
                  }
                  if (finalY < -61) {
                   finalY = finalY + velocity;
                   }
                   else{
                   finalY = -61;
                   }
                   player.setLocation(player.getX(), player.getY() + finalY);
                   if (player.getY() <= 0){
                   cancel();
                   velocity = 0;
                   finalY = 0;
                   player.setLocation(player.getX(), 0);
                    
                   }  
            }
      };
         

         gravityTime = new Timer();
         gravity = new TimerTask() {


            //creates a timer run method that simulates the falling gravity when not grounded
            public void run() {
                if(velocity < 5){
                velocity += 1;
                }
                else{
                velocity = 5;
                }
                //creates the variable the tells where the player is located
                if (finalY < 61) {
                finalY = finalY + velocity;
                }
                else{
                finalY = 61;
                }
                player.setLocation(player.getX(), player.getY() + finalY);
                if (player.getY() >= 1000){
                cancel();
                velocity = 0;
                finalY = 0;
                player.setLocation(player.getX(), 990); 
                }
                
            }
        };

}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
if(spaceHeld == false) {
gravity.cancel();
flightTime.scheduleAtFixedRate(flight, 0 ,33);
spaceHeld = true;
}
else {
gravity.cancel();
}
}
            //Cancel the other timer here so they don't overlap
            gravity.cancel();
}


public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
   gravity.cancel();
   spaceHeld = false;
   flight.cancel();
   gravityTime.scheduleAtFixedRate(gravity, 0, 33);

//Cancel the other timer here so they don't overlap
}
}
}
```

Comment: FYI… `java.util.Timer` was years ago supplanted by the [Executors framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html), as noted in the class’ Javadoc. `TimerTask` was supplanted by any custom class implementing either `Runnable` or `Callable`. The terrible `Calendar` class was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310, specifically `ZonedDateTime`. All this has been covered many times on Stack Overflow.

Comment: 1) You should NOT be using "java.util.Timer". Instead you should be using `javax.swing.Timer` to schedule animation. All updates to the GUI should be done on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. A Swing Timer will invoke the code on the EDT. 2) Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`. I question your logic of starting the animation on a "released" and stopping on a "pressed". I mean every time you press the spacebar it will eventually be released so the animation will always run unless you hold the spacebar in a pressed state.

Comment: Maybe just use the spacebar/pressed as a toggle. When pressed if the Timier is running you stop it. If it is not running you start it? Read the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are section on `Concurrency` which explains what the EDT is and on `How to Use Key Bindings` and `How to Use Timers`.